# Confused about looping through list of people in Python

Tags: python

I'm having issues with an exercise that is asking me to loop through my list of people and print everything that I know about each person while using a dictionary for each person. I'm trying to start out by just getting Python to accept and loop through my dictionaries, but whenever I try to run my code, I get an error message stating: "Value Error: too many values to unpack. (expected 2)"

```
dictionaries_v = {

    'first_name': 'victor',
    'last_name': 'croc',
    'age': 21,
    'city': 'new york',
    }

dictionaries_c = {

    'first_name': 'charmy',
    'last_name': 'bee',
    'age': 8,
    'city': 'new york',
    }

dictionaries_e = {

    'first_name': 'espio',
    'last_name': 'armadilo',
    'age': 15,
    'city': 'new york',
    }

people = ['dictionaries_v', 'dictionaries_c', 'dictionaries_e']

for key, value in people:

    print( "\n" + key + ": " + value)
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is that your list is holding three *strings*. Notice how you wrapped quotes around it. So when you iterate over your list, you will most definitely not be getting the dictionary you expect.

Secondly, `people` is a `list`. So, when you iterate your list, your iterator will hold the dictionary through each iteration.

Knowing this, you simply need to iterate over your list, like any other list:

```
people = [dictionaries_v, dictionaries_c, dictionaries_e]
for d in people:
    print(d)
```

Your output will look like:

```
{'last_name': 'croc', 'age': 21, 'first_name': 'victor', 'city': 'new york'}
{'last_name': 'bee', 'age': 8, 'first_name': 'charmy', 'city': 'new york'}
{'last_name': 'armadilo', 'age': 15, 'first_name': 'espio', 'city': 'new york'}
```

To get specific information from your dictionary, you just use the key in each iteration. Simple example:

```
for d in people:
    print(d['last_name'])
```

Comment: Note that the order of key/value pairs in the output may vary each time you run the program; dictionaries do not necessarily retain order.

Comment: @NeilA. Yes, I'm fully aware of that. I did not mention anything about retaining any order and there is no requirement to retain order. You don't access data in a dictionary like you do in a list. When you do `d['last_name']`, that doesn't mean `last_name` has to be the first entry in the dictionary. That is not how dictionaries work.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It turns out that the single quotes in my list were the main problems.

Answer (score 0):

`people` is a list. You can only get one value at a time from a list. However, its *elements* are dictionaries. So, the following loop would work:

```
for element in people:
    for key, value in element:
        print( "\n" + key + ": " + value)
```

The outer loop goes through each dictionary in `people`, and sets `element` to that dictionary. The inner loop goes through that dictionary and sets `key` to a key and `value` to a value.

Also, you set `people` to `['dictionaries_v', 'dictionaries_c', 'dictionaries_e']`. Instead of setting each of its elements to a string, set it to the variables themselves: `[dictionaries_v, dictionaries_c, dictionaries_e]`.

Comment: It is unnecessary to have nested loops like that. Each iteration of your list will be each dictionary in the list. You just have to access by key using your iterator `element` => `element.get('last_name')`

Comment: The OP asks to print _all_ the information about a person, so the nested for loop achieves getting all the key/value pairs.

Comment: Exactly. Which you can get from the first loop. Each iteration, `element` will hold each dictionary. Strictly based on the data provided, you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding string in list. Please use the variable names.

```
people = [dictionaries_v, dictionaries_c, dictionaries_e]
```

Edit:
Adding more code that fixes the problem of unpacking below.

```
for person in people:
    for key,value in person:
        print key, " : ", value
```

Comment: This still wouldn't fix the problem of too many values to unpack.